# How to use an if/else statement at the same time as a loop?

Tags: javascript

What I have:  I have a box that is constantly switching between being red and being blue every time it's clicked on. Every time the box is clicked on, the player gets a point.

What I want:  When the box is clicked on, and it is red, I want a point added to the player's score. When it is blue and clicked on, I want a message to appear, saying "You lose."

This is my code:

```
var clickedTime;
var createdTime;
var reactionTime;
var clickable;
var score = 1;

function makeBox() {
    var time = (Math.random() * 3000);
    clickable = false;
    console.log(clickable);
    setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "red";
        clickable = true;
        console.log(clickable);
        createdTime = Date.now();
    }, time);
}

makeBox();

document.getElementById("box").onclick = function () {
    clickedTime = Date.now();
    reactionTime = (clickedTime - createdTime) / 1000;
    document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = score;
    this.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    makeBox();
    score++
}
```

I've tried adding (to no success, maybe I'm putting it in the wrong spot):

```
if (clickable=true) {
    makeBox();
    score++
} else {    
    alert("You lose!");
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: For starters, `if (clickable=true) {` should probably be `if (clickable==true) {` - You're assigning `true` to `clickable`, then always going into the first part of the if/else block.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your code:

Instead of calling `if(clickable == true)` which is testing a boolean, you are calling `if(clickable = true)` which is testing an assignment, which will change the result of your code:

```
var clickedTime;
var createdTime;
var reactionTime;
var clickable;
var score = 1;

function makeBox() {
    var time = (Math.random() * 3000);
    clickable = false;
    console.log(clickable);
    setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "red";
        clickable = true;
        console.log(clickable);
        createdTime = Date.now();
    }, time);
}

makeBox();

document.getElementById("box").onclick = function () {
    clickedTime = Date.now();
    reactionTime = (clickedTime - createdTime) / 1000;
    document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = score;
    this.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
        if (clickable==true) {
            makeBox();
            score++
        } else {    
            alert("You lose!");
        }
}
```

Comment: @BenKelsey if this answer helped you, would you mind accepting and/or +1-ing it? Thanks!